# Google URL Shortener not working using file_get_contents

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-get-contents, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I am trying to short url with google api
my site is hosted on google app engine so i cant use **CURL** have to use **file_get_contents**

```
$link = 'http://wwww.example.com';

$data = array('longUrl' => $link, 'key' => $apiKey);
$data = http_build_query($data);

$context = [
  'http' => [
  'method' => 'post',
  'header'=>'Content-Type:application/json',
  'content' => $data
  ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url', false, $context);

$json = json_decode($result);
print_r($json);
```

Above code gives error

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => parseError
                            [message] => Parse Error
                        )

                )

            [code] => 400
            [message] => Parse Error
        )

)
```

Please correct me where i am doing wrong :(

Comment: Did you define `$apiKey`? Try `echo http_build_query($data);` to see what it shows

Comment: yes i have defined apikey and http_build_query($data); is also doing its work..am not getting where problem actually resits ?

Comment: Then try ` echo file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url', false, $context);` to see what the response is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is expecting a JSON-encoded request body (see https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url#resource), so you should really use json_encode instead of http_build_query.

Comment: Thanx a lot :)
I didn't notice its in json form...anyways thanx a lot :) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this, I was able to get it working with the following:

```
$link = 'http://www.google.com';
$data = array('longUrl' => $link);

$context = [
  'http' => [
    'method' => 'post',
    'header'=>'Content-Type:application/json',
    'content' => json_encode($data)
  ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=your_key_here', false, $context);

// Return the JSONified results
$this->output->set_output($result);
```